# Image proccessing Using Python on Raspberry pi "VIDIOC_S_FMT error 16, Device or resource busy"

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I have installed Python libraries, installed Intex USB web cam on raspberry.
While executing python script its giving error message.

> VIDIOC_S_FMT error 16, Device or resource busy

Can anyone help me? How can I solve this error message?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is "motion"

kill it

```
sudo ps -aux | grep motion
sudo kill -9 id_of_motion
```